# How to setup dynamic svn branches - a deviation from normal strategies

Tags: branching-and-merging

I have a not so normal requirement -

I have an SVN project with one trunk; one dev branch & may feature branches. Every  team member pulls out feature branch(not in any particular sequence) from dev and start coding and we all do in parallel.

Suppose i have 10 requirements so 10 feature branches (1,2,..., 10) and all are worked upon in parallel. After coding we merge all these 10 branches in dev branch and deploy in UAT where dev branch is update with all code. But when comes to production movement, there are cases when only some of say 4 (1, 5 , 9 , 10)  features need to be promoted so we have to always retrofit code back from trunk, cherry pick changes from dev branch and merge it into trunk.  But this is very resourceful process & highly error prone because we need to get latest code from trunk and merge selective changes in it and again have to push for another UAT.

Is there a way i can pick any random feature branch and merge into dev and finally into trunk in one go without any retrofitting and saving multiple rounds of UAT?

Answer (score 0):

So we got to devise a strategy after some delibrations.

1. Enable a new prod equivalent environment - preprod/or os
2. New preprod will always be equivalent to prod in terms of code/config
3. Let users signoff eveyrhitng on UAT only
4. Before any prod promotions, users will have to confirm on features to be promoted to prod  well in-advance
5. Once confirmed we will cherrypick/merge these changes into release or trunk and push to preprod
6. Ask users to confirm on preprod
7. Finally push trunk/release to prod